# Como fazer isso? Transition Page dentro de Modal?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-3, bootstrap, modal

Amigos, estou querendo fazer algo semelhante ao que fizeram nessa gif abaixo mas não sei como posso fazer..

A ideia é que, ao clicar em um botão dentro de uma modal, ele direcione para uma ''página'' com esse efeito de transição... Me parece muito com um accordion, mas não sei bem o que eles fizeram.. Alguem tem alguma ideia?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

1º tens de criar essas modais com Materialize ou Bootstrap, ou mesmo do zero.
2º Penso que foi usado o hide() e o show() com uma transição para criar esse efeito
ve um exemplo aqui https://codepen.io/Askwithloud/pen/ZGPOPR

Comment: pois é.. me parece isso mesmo, só que o negócio sobrepõe certinho.. vai dar um trabalho fazer algo parecido hehe